# PROPER way of creating Custom Segue

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, animation, core-animation

Now, yes, there are hundreds of questions (and answers) of how to perform custom segues. However, and I'm no exaggerating, ALL of these answers are wrong (all 50+ I've seen)! Sorry, this might sound harsh, but the truth is, NONE of the suggested answers gives the same (correct) result as Apples built in transitions do (vertical cover etc.).

To be more specific, this is the result that's expected (confirmed with logs):

1. Segue begins (adds view to hierarchy, invokes `viewWillAppear` on destinationVC and `viewWillDisappear` on sourceVC and starts animation).
2. ***animation is performed for the whole duration***
3. Segue ends (animation finished, sets the destinationVC as the current VC, either on stack or modally presented. Invokes `viewDidAppear` on destinationVC and `viewDidDisappear` on sourceVC).

In short: *invoke `viewWillAppear/Disappear` **->** animate transition **->** invoke `viewDidAppear/Disappear`*

Using apples built-in segues, this is the expected behavior but somehow not a single soul except me have had issues with this. A lot of versions even add the destination-view as subview first, animates it then removes it again and calls

`[srcVC presentModalViewController:destVC animated:NO];`

***or***

`[srcVC.navigationController pushViewController:destVC animated:NO];`

causing the view-events to be sent in all kinds of random order (same issue with CoreAnimations).

In my case, all I really want is the "Vertical Cover"-transition reverted (top to bottom), with all other events sent EXACTLY as expected (shown above).

So, am I just supposed to live with all kinds of ugly workarounds (doing my "tasks" in hard-coded methods called whenever I need them to etc.), or is there some hidden ***proper*** way of doing this in a reusable manner?

Funny thing: Even apple [suggest that you do it the "wrong" way](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomSegues/CreatingCustomSegues.html/), making it seem like the right way but with inconsistent outcome compared to their own ways… So my best guess is that apple do this under the hood, and forgot to give enough flexibility for clients to perform the same operations (big flaw in other words), or that I'm just on some bad trip and see some issue that doesn't exist…

Comment: I hope someone has a better answer to your question, but when you mention the fact that Apple seems to suggest you do it the "wrong" way it reminds me that it would not be the first time Apple did not provide devs with the ability to directly mimic first-party behaviors.  The situation that comes to mind is when some of the transition animations were used in various Apple apps a few years before they allowed third-party devs to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this might not be a true answer of how to solve it for custom segues (subclassing UIStoryboardSegue), but it does solve the general issue!

After some casual reading about new features, I stumbled upon a new way to do custom transitions between ViewControllers introduced in iOS7 called nothing more than "Custom Transitions" i guess!
Read about it [here](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/) and [here](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/3871-golden-opportunity-custom-transitions/), or video from WWDC [here](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/#218).

I've just dipped my toes, but basically it is a new, closer to the system way of doing transitions and allows for better control = better looking transitions. After glancing at the example provided by [the blog I referenced](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/3871-golden-opportunity-custom-transitions/) (git found [here](https://github.com/bignerdranch/iOS7Demos)) I can confirm that FINALLY, we are able to do transitions which behave as ONE EXPECTS THEM TO with events fired at the expected occasions!

Since I'm just reading about it I can't give a thorough explanation yet, but check out the links :)

Note: This is maybe not supposed to completely replace custom segues, but can be used in a similar fashion (check examples) so if you need that little extra fancy transition, this is definitely the way to go by the looks of it! Basically you setup segues in the storyboard, and hook up the correct transition-delegates in the `prepareForSegue:`-method.