# Proper way of performing custom transitions with custom segues - WITHOUT SIDE EFFECTS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue, transition

Considering that there are many tutorials available online that show you how to use custom UIStoryboardSegue's to do custom animated transitions between view controllers, I am wondering if there is a "proper" way to do it.

**I should note, I am looking at how to do this modally, not with a navigation controller.**

I realize that there are new ways that are tailored specifically for the purpose of animating a transition between view controllers in iOS 7 but what if I needed to target iOS 6? Or what if there is a shortcoming (which there is, see my SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540461/unwind-with-more-than-1-segue-using-ios-7-uiviewcontroller-transition-animations)) in the iOS 7 way of doing it that is easily addressed by using the custom segue approach.

The issue is that most of the tutorials go something like this:

In your custom segue perform method, you will first add one view controller's view to the other one and then perform whatever custom animation you want. Then after the animation has finished you will call (if presenting or dismissing modally)

```
[sourceViewController presentViewController:destinationViewController animated:NO completion:NULL]
```

The problem with this approach is that the viewWillAppear: and viewDidAppear: are called twice and viewWillDisappear etc. is called once, all within the transition animation. This is not desired behavior.

Is there a proper way that this can be accomplished? For further discussion of this issue, please see the [tutorial](http://dadabeatnik.wordpress.com/2013/10/13/custom-segues/comment-page-1/#comment-479) posted by Phil Beauvoir on his blog and scroll down to the comments.

Furthermore, I have found someone else has asked nearly this same exact question, however I am still asking mine as there are a couple of aspects that my research has uncovered that aren't addressed in his [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311374/proper-way-of-creating-custom-segue). Also, the answer given on his question does not address the question but offers another approach, namely the iOS 7 approach which is not working for my particular need.

Comment: This question is kind of broad and non-specific. I don't know that there is "one proper way" to do a transition, is there a specific transition you're trying to accomplish? Are the side effects you're trying to avoid just the incorrect number (and timing?) of the view appearance callbacks, or is there something more?

Comment: @rdelmar No disrespect intended, but this question is neither broad or non-specific. If you read through the question and check out the links you will see that all of the suggested ways of performing a custom animation (the animation itself is irrelevant—just know that it is custom) you will see that they are flawed and have side effects. I believe Phil Beauvoir's tutorial is one of the more simplistic yet thorough tuts available on the subject, and by following it and testing his sample you can see that there are unwanted side effects. So, once again, is there a proper way???

Comment: @rdelmar And yes, the side effects are that the view appearance callbacks are called an incorrect number of times (and some are called that really shouldn't be—I'm looking at you viewWillDisappear:) These can be worked around, but there is obviously something wrong with how the custom segue is being performed. Apple's own segue's don't cause these side effects.

Comment: I have read all your links, but my point is that there may not be one single proper way to do this. For instance, when using a navigation controller, you have a container controller present, but with a modal presentation you don't. These might need different approaches to avoid the side effects.

Comment: @rdelmar I see your point. I will edit my answer to specifically be for modal presentation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an ideal way to do this. As mentioned in one of the comments to other questions you linked to, Apple hasn't given us access to everything we need to duplicate their modal transition. Specifically, the presentingViewController and presentedViewController properties are read only, so we can't set them. The trouble with the excess calls to the view callbacks is putting in the call to presentViewController:animated:completion: in the completion block of the transition, so eliminating that call solves most of that particular problem.

The closest I could come to duplicating Apple's modal transition (but from the top) was to do it like this:

```
#import "CoverVerticalDown.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "BlueViewController.h"

@implementation CoverVerticalDown

-(void)perform {
    ViewController *s = self.sourceViewController;
    BlueViewController *d = self.destinationViewController;
    [s.view.window addSubview: d.view];
    d.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -480, 320, 480);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        d.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"Starting completion block of transition");
        [s.view removeFromSuperview];
        s.rdPresentedViewController = d;
        d.rdPresentingViewcontroller = s;
    }];
}
```

This does leave the final state the same as a modal transition -- that is, the window has only one view (the new view), the rootViewController of the window is still the source view controller, and there are no child view controllers. But as you can see, to do this, the segue needs to "know" (by imports) what the source and destination controller classes are, so I can set their custom rdPresentedViewController and rdPresentingViewController properties. At least the first of these needs to be set so that the presented controller is retained (that could be done in prepareForSegue I guess though, so maybe you wouldn't have to have this in the segue code). There is one difference in the callback sequence from the standard modal -- the viewWillDisappear method of the source controller is not called until the completion block, whereas it's called during the transition in the normal modal. This method, also does not take into account rotation,, so if you rotate the device and then do the transition, it will come in from the side. To fix that, you would have to do the rotation transformation yourself.

Comment: I think there's another timing issue -- the viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear methods of the destination controller are both called during the transition. So, the number of these callbacks is correct, and they're in the correct order (I think), but the timing is still a little off.

Comment: So, to play devil's advocate for a moment, other than the fact that it is a hacky approach to the problem, and you will have to be careful with what code you execute in the appearance methods of the vc's, what other potential issues could you run into if you just used the tutorial written by Phil that I have linked in my question?

Comment: @daveMac, I'm not sure since I haven't tried his code, but I thought your main problem was the excess callbacks, which that method doesn't fix, correct?  What behavior do you really need? You can change the code I have above to add the destination controller as a child viewController, which sets the childViewController and parentViewController properties, which you can use in lieu of the presented and presentingViewController properties (and retains the child). You can also add the subview to the source instead of the window which gives you proper rotation behavior (but no view disappears).

Comment: The excess callbacks are my issue, I was just curious to know if you knew of any issues that this could cause other than the obvious.